# Show images in twitter widget

Tags: twitter

Is there anything I can add to the twitter widget (the one available on the twitter website) to make images mentioned in tweets appear below the tweet text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Twitter widget does not have that functionality. You will have to write your own or use a third party widget.

Comment: is there any way to process the output from the twitter widget?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken it's an iframe, so the answer is no. You could probably try using the Twitter Search API using JSONP.